# jquery selector needed to select next table from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need a selector that basically starts at the element that I have clicked and finds the next item with a certain class on the page. See my example below:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Blah blah blah</td>
<td><p class="click">Fire jquery</p></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="hidden">
<tr>
<td>blah blah blah</td>
<td>blah blah blah</td>
</tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.hidden').hide()

$('.click').click(function() {
$(this).next('.hidden').fadeIn()
})

})
```

So basically i want to hide everything with the class of hidden when the page loads. Then when something with a class of click is clicked it should scan down the page for the next element with a class of hidden and fade it in. I would just do ('.hidden').fadeIn() but iv got more than one hidden item so it fades all of them in and I only want the next one to be faded in.

Hope you understand all this, I will be very grateful for anyone that can help

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`next('.hidden')` fails because it searches for immediate siblings - that is, on the same `<td>` as the `click` element.
Try finding the `<table>`, and look for its sibling:

```
$(this).closest('table').next('.hidden').fadeIn();
```

or

```
$(this).closest('table').next('.hidden:hidden').fadeIn();
```

If you want to create a semantic connection between a `click` and its `hidden`, consider wrapping them both in a `div`, for example:

```
<div class="Group">
  <p class="click">Fire jquery</p>
  <table class="hidden" />
</div>

$(this).closest('.Group').find('.hidden').fadeIn();
```